# Jquery not working after ajax refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using a jquery code to check all checkboxes and I do like that:

```js
var JQ7=jQuery.noConflict();
JQ7(document).ready(function(){
JQ7("#chkAll").click(function(){
    JQ7(".chk").prop("checked",JQ7("#chkAll").prop("checked"))
}) 
});
...
<input type="checkbox" id="chkAll" />   
...
<input type="checkbox" class="chk" />
```

I put all code in the ajax page. At the first loading it works fine but after I refresh, it doesn't work for me. Here is the ajax code :

```js
 function showUser(str,pageno,type,sub)
 {
     if (str=="" || pageno=="" || type=="" || sub== "")
 {
     document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
     return;
 }
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
     xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
     xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
         document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     }
 }

 xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php echo $view['router']->generate('listing') ?>?page="+pageno+"&genre="+str+"&cat="+type+"&subcat="+sub,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 }
```

Comment: What does the ajax call return? Does it dynamically generate `#chkAll`?

Comment: If `chkAll` is inside `txtHint` you need to attach the click even again as this would be a new DOM element.

Comment: @Gabriel Yes it's inside 'txtHint' div,but I'm not a very professional in javascript to understand what you mean?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you're constructing parts of your page dynamically, you'll need to attach your event handlers with $(...).on(), otherwise the event handlers will be lost when the elements are replaced. Alternatively, you can also reattach the event handlers again  when that part of the page is modified.

You need to attach your event handlers with the second selector parameter like so:

```
$("#parent").on("click", ".item-to-be-clicked", function () {
    ...
});
```

Example of delegated vs non delegated event handler: http://jsfiddle.net/pj5EW/

Answer (score 5):

Piggybacking on Lie Ryan's answer:

As it's currently coded, your click handler will only apply to elements that already exist in the DOM. When you dynamically generate those elements after the DOM loads, your click handler won't see them.

You can use jQuery's [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to [delegate the event](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events). This puts the handler on the document (rather than the element) and allows you to select elements that are added to the page after the DOM loads:

```
JQ7(document).on('click','#chkAll',function(){
  var is_checked=this.checked;
  JQ7(".chk").prop("checked",is_checked);
});
```